# How to understand the KL-divergence between two non-negative matrices

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonnegative-matrices

I am reading Non-negative Matrix algorithm using KL-divergence as metric.

The KL-divergence is known as $D(P,Q)=\sum_i P(i)log\frac{P(i)}{Q(i)}$ for discrete distribution.

However, the KL-divergence between two non-negative matrix shows as $D(A,B)=\sum_{i,j} A_{i,j}\log\frac{A_{i,j}}{B_{i,j}}+\sum_{i,j} B_{i,j}-\sum_{i,j}A_{i,j}$

I don't understand where is the function is derived from?

Comment: 1) Could you give a complete reference to the paper you are reading ? Is it [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221080181_Kullback-Leibler_Divergence_for_Nonnegative_Matrix_Factorization/) ? 2) Somewhat connected: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3085007_The_Kullback-Leibler_Divergence_Rate_Between_Markov_Sources/l

Comment: Interesting connection [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3661938/305862). Besides, please answer my previous question.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your reply. I think I found the answer in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.01935.pdf). Each element is treated as Poisson distribution. I haven't finish all equation, but that should be the reason.